# Run function on 1 sheet only instead of .forEach

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I believe this will be a super easy question for you. I downloaded a YT script to automatically update YT views on Google Sheets which you can find here (https://developers.google.com/gsuite/solutions/youtube-tracker).

I have a spreadsheet with 12 tabs and the code has a function to go through every tab in the spreadsheet.

```
function markVideos() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  
  // Runs through process for each tab in Spreadsheet.
  sheets.forEach(function(dataSheet) {
    var tabName = dataSheet.getName();
    var range = dataSheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = range.getNumRows();
    var rows = range.getValues();
    var headerRow = rows[0];
```

I want to change it to apply to a specific tab only, let's say "Sheet12", instead of running it for every tab.

```
function markVideos() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet12");
  
  // Runs through process for each tab in Spreadsheet.
  function NameOfTheFunction(dataSheet) {
    var tabName = dataSheet.getName();
    var range = dataSheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = range.getNumRows();
    var rows = range.getValues();
    var headerRow = rows[0];
```

I tried this but had no luck because it doesn't seem to be applying the function to the specific sheet. I believe this is super easy fix but I have no idea about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `forEach` statement and use [getSheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) instead of `getSheets`:

```
function markVideos() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tabName = 'Sheet12';
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName(tabName)   
  var range = dataSheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var rows = range.getValues();
  var headerRow = rows[0];         
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array ForEach() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp) calls a function once for each element in an array. That is why a function must be defined that will take an array element `function(dataSheet)`

Since you only need to access 1 sheet based on its sheet name.
You don't need to define a function to access the properties of that sheet.

**Sample:**

[image]

**Sample Code:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  
  var tabName = sheets.getName();
  var range = sheets.getDataRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var rows = range.getValues();
  var headerRow = rows[0]; 
  
  Logger.log(tabName);
  Logger.log(numRows);
  Logger.log(rows);
  Logger.log(headerRow);
}
```

**Logger Log Output:**

[image]

**References:**

[Class Sheet Methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

[SpreadsheetApp Methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)